# flexslider on small screens

Tags: css, flexslider

I'm using the Sparkling theme on a Wordpress site. The theme uses Flexslider within a div at the top of the page. Each slide contains an image along with a div containing a post title and excerpt.

The slider is built within header.php like in this function:

```
function sparkling_featured_slider() {
   if ( is_front_page() && of_get_option( 'sparkling_slider_checkbox' ) == 1 ) {
      echo '<div class="flexslider">';
         echo '<ul class="slides">';
            $count = of_get_option( 'sparkling_slide_number' );
            $slidecat =of_get_option( 'sparkling_slide_categories' );

            $query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' =>$slidecat,'posts_per_page' =>$count ) );
            if ($query->have_posts()) :
               while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

               echo '<li>';
               if ( (function_exists( 'has_post_thumbnail' )) && ( has_post_thumbnail() ) ) :
                 echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
               endif;

               echo '<div class="flex-caption">';
                  if ( get_the_title() != '' ) echo '<h2 class="entry-title">'. get_the_title().'</h2>';
                  if ( get_the_excerpt() != '' ) echo '<div class="excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt() .'</div>';
              echo '</div>';
          echo '</li>';
          endwhile;
        endif;

  echo '</ul>';

echo ' </div>';
```

}
}
endif;

And the resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="top-section">
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img width="1920" height="512" src="http://pathtoslider.jpeg" 
                    class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" 
                    alt="slide1" 
                    srcset="pathstodifferentresolutions.jpg" 
                    sizes="(max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px" />
                <div class="flex-caption">
                    <h2 class="entry-title">Tomatoes</h2>
                    <div class="excerpt">Knowledge is knowing that tomatoes are a fruit. Wisdom is knowing not to put them in a fruit salad.</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                ..more slides..
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container main-content-area">
```

By default it suppresses the flex-caption on small screens by setting display:none in a media query, but I want to display it, so I set the display to inline in my own media query.

This leads to another problem because the whole top-section div is the height of the image and there isn't necessarily room for the flex-caption.

I would like the bottom of the entry-title to be aligned with the bottom of the image, and the excerpt immediately below the image, which I accomplish like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .flex-caption {
    display: inline;
    bottom: 0;
   }
  .entry-title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .excerpt {
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

but this doesn't resize the top-section div, so I'm overwriting the main-content-area.

I've tried lots of different things, including trying `height:auto` just about everywhere.

I can't figure out how the slider height is set. It seems to be within get_the_post_thumbnail. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting image height in functions.php 
`function the_post_thumbnail( $size = 'post-thumbnail', $attr = '' )`.

Comment: Nope. Trying ```get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large')``` changed the size specified in the img tag but didn't change the functionality at all